# Remove automatically create mount point when mount unit is stopped/unmounted

Tags: systemd, mount, systemd-mount

I've been laboring under the false assumption that mount points which are automatically created by `systemd` would also be automatically deleted, too. When I learned that `systemd` creates mount points for mount units if their mount points don't already exist, I figured that it behaved like macOS which creates and deletes mount points in `/Volumes`, respectively, before mounting and after unmounting a device.

One of my Linux setups is configured—either through a mount unit or `fstab`, depending on whicheber seems better at any given moment—to mount a tmpfs at `/mnt`. It's my equivalent of `/Volumes`.  My mount units use `/mnt/<mount point name>` as their respective mount points. An example is mounting `/dev/cdrom` at `/mnt/cdrom`. (A side request: if someone could also tell me how to get non-root users' mounts that are performed with tools like `udisksctl` to mount in `/mnt` instead, that would be nice.)

I tried looking for a solution in the form of a directive I could add to each mount unit file that would call `rmdir` on its own mount point when the mount unit is "stopped", but there was nothing explicit in the search results I turned up. `ExecStop` was unrecognized in mount units by `systemctl`.

Hopefully, there's a graceful solution that is intended `systemd` developers for just this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in way to do this, but it can be done with a service template file:

```ini
# /etc/systemd/system/cleanup-mount-point@.service
[Unit]
Description=Remove mount point when stopped
Before=%i.mount
PartOf=%i.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=rmdir %f
```

Then you can just add this line to the `[Unit]` section of your mount unit:

```ini
Wants=cleanup-mount-point@%N.service
```

where `%N`, the name of the mount unit, becomes the `%i` in the above service template.

Or, if you're feeling adventurous, you can use a drop-in file to apply it to all mount units:

```ini
# /etc/systemd/system/mount.d/10-cleanup-mount-points.conf
[Unit]
Wants=cleanup-mount-point@%i.service
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. For any systemd novices (like myself) out there, note that `%i` takes the instance name after the @. So, the second code block above only works if the mount unit itself is a template (with an @ in its name).

Comment: ...but unfortunately, mount units cannot be templated (man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.mount.5), so there's no @ or %i in mount units. The second code block should have `%N` (the full unit name) instead of `%i` (the part after the @, which is necessarily empty.)