# systemd-mount and automatic deletion of mount point on USB removal

Tags: systemd, udev, usb-drive, yocto, systemd-mount

On a `systemd` based embedded system, built with `yocto`, I'm trying to use `systemd-mount` for automatically mounting USB drives whenever those are plugged in.

Following the [official manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-mount.html), I created a `udev` rule like the following:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", \
    RUN{program}+="/usr/bin/systemd-mount --bind-device --no-block --automount=yes --collect $devnode"
```

The volumes get mounted correctly, but when I remove the device the mount points are left on filesystem.
Looking at the manual, it seems to me that the option `--bind-device` should provide exactly this kind of feature:

> If set, the automount point will be removed automatically when the backing device vanishes.

But this is not the case.

How can I manage to get the mount point removed as soon the device is unplugged?
Do I need to implement some kind of magic script to be invoked by `udev` on usb removal, or I'm missing something on `systemd` side?

Answer (score 0):

According source [systemd.mount-tool](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/e4aab5cf1a00bbb73f325f4f785dd4171ccdae77/src/mount/mount-tool.c#L482) `--bind-device` only add `After=` and `BindsTo=` rows in generated unit file (`/run/systemd/transient/*.{automount,mount}`)
The mountpoint dirs are  not autoremove(

looks like you need to [make some magic script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606314/remove-automatically-create-mount-point-when-mount-unit-is-stopped-unmounted)

Comment: Thank you!
That problem is no longer my problem, but I actually implemented a magic script to handle the deletion.